# Delete from i-th element of std::multiset to the end

Tags: c++, c++11, multiset

`i` is `k` in my code, just used `i` for the future users.

```
std::multiset<std::pair<Point::FT, int> > res;
res.erase(res.begin() + k, res.end());
```

Error:

no match for operator +

How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) to advance the iterator `k` positions

```
res.erase(std::next(res.begin(), k), res.end());
```

The reason your code fails to compile is because `std::multiset` iterators are [BidirectionalIterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), so they only implement pre/post increment/decrement operators, so you need to *walk* the iterator the desired number of positions, which `std::next` will do for you.

Comment: Didn't know about `std::next`! Thank you sir.

Comment: What is the method for < C++11?

Comment: @0x499602D2 [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance). The sucky part about it is that because it takes a reference to the iterator to be advanced, you need to first initialize a variable with the `begin()` iterator, and pass that to `advance`. No pretty one-liner like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator `operator+` requires that it operate on random access iterators, because addition for non-random-access iterators is a linear operation. The iterators used by a `multiset` are bidirectional, so you can't do direct addition.

@Praetorian answered the question exactly as written, but I'm going to argue that you're trying to solve the wrong problem/asking the wrong question.

If you want to use indexing in your container, you should strongly prefer `vector` instead (possibly sorted from time to time). Alternately maybe you know the *key* of the item you want to erase from to the end. Then you can use logarithmic time `find` to find the iterator and erase from there to the end.

If you actually need a sorted, indexable, ordered container, I would suggest `boost::multi_index` instead of any standard container.

Comment: Well Mark, I want ordering, which vector doesn't provide. Moreover, I know thought of way to avoid deletion, which was the only part which required indexing.